# Ho to set the right URL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to go to a specific URL based on the User's id. When I'm on the home page I can see user's email as well as user's id just fine by doing this:

```
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Hola <strong>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</strong><br/> Welcome!
                   {{Auth::user()->email}} // tester@gmail.com
                   {{Auth::user()->id}}    // 15
                </div>
```

**But after clicking on this Link:**

```
           <a href="{{ url('/edit-user/Auth::user()->id') }}">Edit User</a>
```

I would like to go to:
     http://localhost:8000/edit-user/15

But when I click on that link I get this link:

```
                  http://localhost:8000/edit-user/Auth::user()-%3Eid
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

**Here's my routes.php**

```
 Route::get('edit-user/{id}', 'HomeController@edit');
```

**Here's my HomeController:**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $students = Student::where("id", $id)->first();
    return view('edit-user', compact('students'));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single quotes is breaking it. You need to use this:

```
       <a href="{{ url('/edit-user/' . Auth::user()->id) }}">Edit User</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip!

Comment: Yepp, that should do it! And just a suggestion, look into named routes. It's much better than hard code URL's in your HTML